Issue in Mathematica plot for Imaginary part
I am trying to plot a function, but the output is not continuous. Here is my code
Plot[(
  E^(-(s/lm))
    v (lm - 
     2 lm Hypergeometric2F1[1, -(lg/lm), 1 - lg/lm, E^(s/lg)] - 
     2 E^(s/lm) (s - lg Log[1 - E^(s/lg)])))/H, {s, 3, 4}]

I then tried to plot the imaginary part to see if the empty space between the lines in the above graph comes from an imaginary number.
Plot[Im[(
  E^(-(s/lm))
    v (lm - 
     2 lm Hypergeometric2F1[1, -(lg/lm), 1 - lg/lm, E^(s/lg)] - 
     2 E^(s/lm) (s - lg Log[1 - E^(s/lg)])))/H], {s, 3, 4}]

The imaginary part is small, and I am not sure if the imaginary part is numerical error, or they are these small imaginary parts that make the output of the plot to have empty spaces between the lines. Could someone please help me?
I used H=0.1, v=0.5, lg=1; lm=2;

Without the values that you used for {H, lg, lm, v}, we cannot reproduce your results.

Thanks for your comments. Added @BobHanlon

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f = (E^(-(s/lm))  v  (lm - 
       2  lm  Hypergeometric2F1[1, -(lg/lm), 1 - lg/lm, E^(s/lg)] - 
       2  E^(s/lm)  (s - lg  Log[1 - E^(s/lg)])))/H /. {H -> 0.1, v -> 0.5, 
   lg -> 1, lm -> 2}

(* 5. E^(-s/2) (2 - 4 Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 1, 1/2, E^s] - 
   2 E^(s/2) (s - Log[1 - E^s])) *)

If you are getting imaginary artifacts with your version, try using exact values and simplifying.
f2 = (E^(-(s/lm))  v  (lm - 
         2  lm  Hypergeometric2F1[1, -(lg/lm), 1 - lg/lm, E^(s/lg)] - 
         2  E^(s/lm)  (s - lg  Log[1 - E^(s/lg)])))/H /. {H -> 1/10, v -> 1/2,
      lg -> 1, lm -> 2} // FunctionExpand // Simplify

(* 10 (-E^(-s/2) - s + 2 E^(-s/2) Sqrt[E^s] ArcTanh[Sqrt[E^s]] + Log[1 - E^s]) *)

Both plots are continuous
Plot[{f, f2}, {s, 3, 4},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]


EDIT:  Or for a more robust solution, use ComplexExpand with f2
f3 = Assuming[s > 0, 
  f2 // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // Simplify]

(* 10 (-E^(-s/2) - s + 2 Log[1 + E^(s/2)]) *)

FunctionDomain[f3, s]

(* True *)

Although f3 was developed assuming s > 0, f3 == f2 for real s
Assuming[s ∈ Reals, 
 ComplexExpand[f2 == f3, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // FullSimplify]

(* True *)

